# compression format supported by all OS

Tags: operating-system, compression, visitors

I am going to offer site visitors a compressed file ( for gallery images ).  **What is the compression format that is supported by ALL operating systems?**

Visitors might have any operating system like windows, mac, linux etc. I want all visitors ( do not have technical knowledge ) to download compressed file and see images without installing any additional compression tool.

Hope I explained what I need.

Thanks

Comment: I think windows only supports zip natively, so least common denominator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No compression format is supported by literally all operating systems. Some OSes don't even have a disk I/O or network I/O.

Having said that, use `.zip` as that's natively supported by Windows, it's the most popular format, and it's the core of several other file formats including Open Document Format and Java Archive (`jar`). *All* operating systems that are able to run Java are *technically* able to unpack zip files. I also assume that almost all modern operating systems have the support to unpack .zip files built in.

If you want to support ancient Unix machines as well, offer `.tar.gz` beside `.zip`. Even then, said ancient Unix machines should be able to unpack `.zip` as well.

Answer (score 3):

Zip, hands down.  Built in support in OSX and Windows XP and up.  Linux is too diverse to make any assumptions.

Comment: Zip is supported on every Linux I've used. If not, it's trivial to install.